# Android: prettier TabLayout?

Tags: android

I only want to use text in the tabs of my TabLayout.  Unfortunately, by default, the Tabs are very large and the text is very small.  I see no way of adjusting the size of the text or height of the tabs, without using `TabSpec.setIndicator(View)`; which would be very undesirable because then I would have define a specific layout, selector, selected image, unselected image, etc... so my tabs would not fit the look and feel of each device.  Is there a convenient way to customize the Tab appearance?

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("system").setIndicator("My first tab").setContent(R.id.fileBrowserTabHostSystemList));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("recent").setIndicator("My Second tab").setContent(R.id.fileBrowserTabHostRecentList));
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best example I have come across: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: I really prefer not to do this, because I would like my tabs to use the local look and feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to change the tab height in a nice way:

```
    final int tabChildrenCount = tabWidget.getChildCount();
    View currentTab;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabChildrenCount; i++) {
        currentTab= tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
        currentTab.getLayoutParams().height = 32;
    }
    tabWidget.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    tabWidget.requestLayout();
```

[image: Tabs with smaller height]

I also tried to get the height of the title in the tab and to set tab's height to it:

```
currentTab.findViewById(android.R.id.title).getHeight();
// also tried with getMeasuredHeight()
```

but it returns 0 since it was in the onCreate() method and the view seems to not know its size at that moment. LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT is no good for the tab height, because it acted as FILL_PARENT.

Note, however, that this solution only assumes that the title of the tab will fit in 32 pixels.

Still the safest guess is to manually do the layout (as already posted http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136). Get the resources from Android Repository and customtize :)

Comment: I guess there is no good way to go about this.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ab11, check the new solution.